# Sheafification of the Presheaf of continuous and bounded functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space. $U\subset X$ open.
$\mathfrak{B}(U) = \{f:U\to \mathbb{R}| f \textrm{ continuous and bounded}\}$ is a presheaf.

I would like to see the sheafification of this presheaf. I have a solution from my tutorial but I don't understand all the steps:

$\mathfrak{B}^g(U):= \{(f_x)\in\prod\limits_{x\in U}\mathfrak{B}_x| \forall x\in U, \exists W\subset U, x\in W, g\in \mathfrak{B}(W) \textrm{ s.t. }\forall w\in W: g_W = f_W\}$.
$\mathfrak{B}_x = \{f_x:U_x\to\mathbb{R}|U_x\textrm{ ''small enough'' s.t. } f_x\textrm{ continuous and bounded}\}$.
But if $U_x$ is for example the preimage of $B_\epsilon(f(x))$ of $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ then $f_x$ is bounded and hence $\mathfrak{B}_x=\{f_x:U_x\to\mathbb{R}| f_x \textrm{ continuous}\}$.

(I don't understand what he wanted to tell with this part, and also I am not sure if I wrote $B$ correctly or if it should be $\mathfrak{B}$. We defined $B_\epsilon(0)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}: |x|<\epsilon\}$ in the proof for showing that $\mathfrak{B}$ is not a sheaf.)


Now choose $W=U_x$ for a $x\in U$. So $g=f_x$ and hence $g_w=f_w$ $\forall w\in W\Rightarrow \mathfrak{B}^g(U)=\{f:U\to\mathbb{R}| f \textrm{ continuous}\}$.

I would be really happy if someone could help me understand this example. Maybe you also have a better explanaition of the sheafification?

Thanks and best, Luca

Comment: A better explanation? The difficulty would be to find a worse one...

Comment: I am struggeling at the point where he sais for $U_x$ we have that $f_x$ is bounded and so $B_x=\{f_x:U_x\to\mathbb{R}\}$. So he sais that $f_x$ is bounded on $U_x$ for all $f_x:U_x\to\mathbb{R}$? Do you know what I mean? And yes, I am really happy to have this tutor :)

Comment: Here is the correct order for the quantifiers: given a continuous function $f:U\to \mathbb R$,  then for every $x\in U$ there exists an open neighbourhood $U_x\subset U$ of $x$ such that $f$ is bounded on  $U_x$. This is what is meant with "continuous functions are locally bounded" in my answer. By the way, I am criticizing a mathematical explanation, not your tutor.

Comment: ok! Thank you, It's now clearer. :) is it OK if I accept Hurkyl's answer? Just because it's like a more detailed version of yours..

Comment: I confess I feel a little silly that I was so busy sketching how the argument goes that I forgot to mention why we would have even thought it should be true in the first place!

Comment: Dear Luca: it is absolutely OK if you accept Hurkyl's fine answer, which is definitely more detailed than mine .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're using $\mathfrak{B}^g$ to mean the sheafification of $\mathfrak{B}$? I'll assume so.

There is an evident morphism $\mathfrak{B} \to \mathcal{C}$ from the presheaf of bounded continuous functions to the sheaf of continuous functions. This factors uniquely into $\mathfrak{B} \to \mathfrak{B}^g \to \mathcal{C}$, where the first map is the canonical map for the sheafification.

The goal of this proof is to understand these morphisms by understanding how it looks on the *stalks* of the sheaves.

The key point is that sheafification induces isomorphisms on all of the stalks. And furthermore, a morphism of sheaves is an isomorphism if and only if it induces an isomorphism on all of the stalks.

Thus, by showing that $\mathfrak{B} \to \mathcal{C}$ induces isomorphisms on the stalks of these presheaves, we can conclude that $\mathcal{C}$ *is* a sheafification of $\mathfrak{B}$.

The key idea to manage this proof is the defining property of continuity: if $f$ is continuous at $x$, you can ensure that $f(y)$ is as close to $f(x)$ as you like by restricting $y$ to an appropriate neighborhood of $x$.

Answer (score 17):

The sheafification of your presheaf $\mathfrak{B}$ is the sheaf $\mathcal  C$ of continuous functions on $X$.
This is immediate once you realize that every continuous $U\to \mathbb R$ is locally  bounded.

**Edit: a few words about sheafification in general**
Given a presheaf $\mathcal F$ on a topological space $X$, one associates to it a sheaf $\mathcal F^+$, its sheafification.
The construction is a bit opaque  for a beginner, involving   families of germs of sections on open subsets $U\subset X$.
If, however, by a stroke of luck $\mathcal F\subset \mathcal G$ somehow happens to be a subpresheaf of a **sheaf** $\mathcal G$, sheafification of $\mathcal F$ becomes very easy: one just defines $$\mathcal F^+(U)=\{g\in \mathcal G(U)|g \; \text {is locally in} \; \mathcal F\}$$ the last condition meaning that there exists a covering $(U_i)$ of $U$ (depending on $g$ !)  such that $g|U_i\in \mathcal F(U_i)\subset \mathcal G(U_i)$.
So my (too) crisp answer meant that you should apply this to $\mathcal F=\mathfrak{B}$ and $\mathcal G=\mathcal C$.

And now for the good news: this construction actually works for **all** presheaves $\mathcal F$.
The trick is to construct a huge sheaf $\mathcal G$ in which to embed an arbitrary presheaf $\mathcal F$.
  Well, just take $\mathcal G(U)=\prod_{x\in U} \mathcal F_x$ with the obvious restrictions.
The embedding is of course given by $$  \mathcal F(U)\hookrightarrow \mathcal G(U)=\prod_{x\in U} \mathcal F_x: s\mapsto (s_x)_{x\in U}$$
And this is the  explanation for the recipe, apparently drawn out of the blue, everybody gives for sheafifying a presheaf.

Comment: What do you mean with 'depending on g !' ?

Comment: Dear @Ryan, I mean exactly what I write: the covering $(U_i)$ of $U$ depends on the element $g$. For example if you take a $g$ already in the original presheaf,  $g\in \mathcal F(U)$, you may take the covering with  just one piece, namely $U$ itself. But in Luca's question for example, if you take $X=U=\mathbb R$  and $g(x)=x$, the covering might be $U_i=(i-2,i+2)$ or $U_i=(-i,+i)$ but you MUST have infinitely many different  $U_i$'s in the covering .

Comment: Thank you for answering! 


Shouldn't it be for every cover of U? 
You only want g in F(U) if you can use the glueing axiom for every cover.

Comment: Dear @Ryan: no,  checking that one suitable coverof $U$ exists for each $g$ suffices. That $\mathcal F^+$ then satisfies the sheaf axioms for all covers  is automatic.

Comment: +1 for the edit. But I think one needs to be a bit careful. Just an arbitrary huge sheaf in which the presheaf is embedded will not work. One needs the minimal such :).

Comment: @Vishtal. Not at all: an arbitrary huge sheaf in which the presheaf is embedded will work perfectly. There is absolutely no requirement of minimality . For example  the sheaf $\mathcal G(U)=\prod_{x\in U} \mathcal F_x$ I evoke at the end of my answer is truly  huge  and yet is the best (=most canonical) choice possible. I challenge you to find another sheafification for an arbitrary  presheaf.